# Hide 'like' and 'comment' on stream posts from my website

Tags: php, facebook

I have a web app that uses php to post to a user's Facebook stream.  I know I can add custom actions, which appear next to 'like' and 'comment' at the bottom of the post, but can I hide the like and comment links themselves?

Comment: Where is the site? Show us HTML + CSS code of the page you are talking about.

Comment: The posts I'm referring to appear on Facebook.com in the stream.  I'm using php to post content to FB, not bedding FB content on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not remove the reference in you php file or use CSS and set display: none;

Comment: Sorry, I mean to hide the links on the FB stream.  These links seem to be included by default and I'm curious if they can be hidden.

Comment: As I said, CSS is the way to go but you'll need to stay on top of all of Facebooks changes. All modern browsers have developer tools that will let you look at the CSS elements in use on sections of the page so you know what to override.

Comment: I appreciate the help and I'm sorry to sound so ignorant, but how can I have any control over the case on Facebook.com?

Comment: Sorry, I'm readinf that you've embedded facebook content into your site. If your just pushing to facebook and viewing in Facebook, there is nothing you can do.